# How does plataformatec devise encrypt passwords?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, encryption, devise

In this example the password is `abcd1234` and this is what [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) stored in the database

```
email: edu@example.com
encrypted_password: 9fead460b4eafc9fb4f188e4d6f24536f5849ed7
password_salt: k_c7dqyNKiQbSC_r8grH
```

I'm trying to build a node.js application that checks the plain password against the encrypted data so a javascript example would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have there looks like processed data of what the `devise` created. The `encrypted_password` length is correct for a bcrypt hash, but apparently this hash is encoded with `password_salt` value, which is not a part of `devise` package. Right now your information is not enough to resolve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application was using the [sha1 encryptor](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise-encryptable/blob/master/lib/devise/encryptable/encryptors/sha1.rb) and I made this javascript version of it:

```
function createHash (password, salt) {
  let pepper = ''
  let digest = ''
  const STRETCHES = 10
  for (let i = 0; i < STRETCHES; i++) {
    digest = crypto
      .createHash('sha1')
      .update(`--${salt}--${digest}--${password}--${pepper}--`)
      .digest('hex')
  }
  return digest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses OpenBSD bcrypt() password hashing algorithm

Here is `encryptor.rb` code:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'bcrypt'

module Devise
  module Encryptor
    def self.digest(klass, password)
      if klass.pepper.present?
        password = "#{password}#{klass.pepper}"
      end
      ::BCrypt::Password.create(password, cost: klass.stretches).to_s
    end

    def self.compare(klass, hashed_password, password)
      return false if hashed_password.blank?
      bcrypt   = ::BCrypt::Password.new(hashed_password)
      if klass.pepper.present?
        password = "#{password}#{klass.pepper}"
      end
      password = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, bcrypt.salt)
      Devise.secure_compare(password, hashed_password)
    end
  end
end
```

You could find more [there](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby)

And here is more about [bcrypt.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js)

Example from their readme:

> To check a password:

```
// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compareSync("B4c0/\/", hash); // true
bcrypt.compareSync("not_bacon", hash); // false
```

Comment: I tried to use the javascript bcrypt but it hashes with a different format

Comment: There are 2 possible causes: the plataformatec devise application uses a custom cryptor instead of a default one or there is second layer of encryption between application and database. Also, you should know the application's security keys and the `pepper` value (it is email address by default). If you have no access to the devise application sources - you won't succeed.